# Access denied in ajax call with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting access denied when sending this request to the server through ajax.
I have also done with `XDomainRequest` for the IE browsers 
but I am still getting the access denied problem.
When I run this with my local address it is working but 
it is not working when I use another address.

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.ajax({
    type:callType,
    url:url,
    data:requestBody,
    crossDomain:true,
    success:function (returnData, status, xhr) {
        alert("getDataFromJQuery success");
        alert(url);
        callback(returnData.response ? returnData.response : returnData);
    },
    error:function (jqXHR, exception) {
        alert("getDataFromJQuery error"+JSON.stringify(jqXHR));

        if (errcallback) {
            errcallback(jqXHR, exception);
        } else {
            alert("exception in making [" + url + "] :[" + exception + "]");
        }

    },
    timeout:1200000,
    dataType:dataType,

});
```

Comment: Are you doing a cross domain request? Did you set up a CORS policy? (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)

Comment: What is that `callType`, `json` or `jsonp` or other?

Comment: We dont see values of: callType, url, requestBody and dataType variables.

Answer (score 1):

As per @FritsvanCampen, the place you're asking for data from needs to allow that. If you control that location, make sure the server sets a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header value that allows requests by the domain your requesting page is on.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS for more information that you want to read (but should read anyway =)